# Calculating water flow as function of the height of water above the inlet pipe

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

The Source of Water is Pond where the water level do change randomly. A pipeline of 200mm pipe diameter run for around 2500 m. The Height difference between the level of the inlet pipe and the level of the exit pipe is around 9m. In other word: Water need to run by gravity for 2500 m. Difference in height is 9m.

My question: How I could calculate the water volume/flow received at the exit pipe as function of the height of the water above the inlet pipe.

Ex: If the water in the Pond is covering the inlet pipe by say 10 cm, what is the expected flow at the exit pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in height (9 m vs. 9.01 m) is not significant.

According to this [calculator](http://www.hawsedc.com/engcalcs/Manning-Pipe-Flow.php), the water flow is 23.25 l/min.

Sorry, it is actually, 23.25 l/s.

Comment: Thanks . Could I understand that the height of the water range ( from 10 cm to max 40 cm ) above the inlet pipe should be  insignificant compared to the difference in the elevation between the inlet pipe and the exit pipe ?? 
The Pipe is PVC-U pipe . The current reading of flow is around 6 m3/Hour . 
using the calculator : Pipe inner Di matter = 192 mm . Manning = 0.009 ( for PVC) . Pressure slope = 9m . Ful depth= 100% . i got around 42 m3/Hour . What is wrong in my calculation ?? . Thanks in advance .

Comment: The range in height would change from 9.01 to 9.04 m. It is a 0.3% change. So, the question is, is this height change going to significantly affect the flow? Do I really need the precision?

Comment: Actually i do not know . This a real problem . i got 6 m3/Hour with water level of 10 cm . some one suggest that if i lower the inlet pipe with extra 20 cm to be around 0.3 m below water level i will have dramatic increase in the flow rate . so i just want to make sure before spending a lot of $ to lower the inlet pipe .

Comment: Are there any turns in the pipe, or is it just a straight, unbending tube? The flow is restricted when it goes around corners.

Comment: @LDC3: 9 m + 40 cm = 9.4 m ! But the discrepancy in flow rate of course is much larger.

Comment: @user43527: if the total height drop from water level in pond to outlet is the same, you won't get a significant difference. Tube diameter or water level in pond are the crucial parameters.

Comment: Related [Toricelli's law.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law). If you assume you have an ideal fluid, so no friction or turbulence slowing the flow, the only parameters of importance are height difference between inlet and outlet and the pipe diameter.